# Solr Sort Hybris

Tags: sorting, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a provider, wich index stock for product for every unit, this way:

```
for (Map.Entry<B2BUnitModel, Integer> unit : stockByUnit.entrySet() )
    {
        document.addField(indexedProperty, hasStock(unit.getValue()), unitUid(unit.getKey()));
    }
```

so this is result after index in solr:

```
"localStockForUnt_001_boolean": true,
"localStockForUnt_002_boolean": true,
```

where localStockForUnt is SolrIndexedProperty, 001 and 002 are the units and true or false are the indexed value.

this is the impex to create it:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)`[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];useForSpellchecking[default=false];useForAutocomplete[default=false];fieldValueProvider;valueProviderParameter`
;$solrIndexedType; localStockForUnt       ;boolean ;            ;    ;    ;    ;     ;   ;myResolver;
```

so I added it inside the 'sort' called 'relevance' in hmc, this 'sort' just have this field in hmc.

My doubt is, how can I set to it sort my result using for example localStockForUnt_002_boolean?
I did set sort in controller manually to test, I did set it to "relevance", but since the provider of field used in relevance (localStockForUnt) index two diferent informations, how can I select which one to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you are trying to do here was already been initiated and used in several cases by Hybris, for example:

- `localized` properties like the `name`, indexed as `name_en_string`.
- properties with `currency` like `price` is indexed as `priceValue_eur_double` and also used for Sort.

**For** :`priceValue_eur_double`       |     **For** : `localStockForUnt_001_boolean`.
`priceValue` is the field's name    |     `localStockForUnt` is the field's name.
`eur`is the field qualifier    |    `001` is the field qualifier.
`double` is the field type     |    `boolean` is the field type.

So your case here is not different than these two examples, hence you need just to know how to use what's already exists.

Actually nothing magical about how these two examples works!

1. First of all, add new boolean `attribute` to `SolrIndexedPropertyModel` let's call it `isB2bUnit` :

```xml
<!-- add this to your *-items.xml -->
<itemtype code="SolrIndexedProperty" autocreate="false" generate="false">
    <attributes>

        <attribute qualifier="isB2bUnit" type="java.lang.boolean">
            <persistence type="property" />
            <!-- i would prefer to add a default value here : FALSE -->
        </attribute>

    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

2. Next you have to add the same `boolean attribute` in the `IndexedProperty` dto :

```xml
<!-- add this to your *-beans.xml -->
<bean class="de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.config.IndexedProperty">

    <property name="isB2bUnit" type="boolean"/>     

</bean>
```

3. Then you need to override `DefaultIndexedPropertyPopulator` it's the responsible for converting from `SolrIndexedProperty` to `IndexedProperty`:

```java
public class MyIndexedPropertyPopulator extends DefaultIndexedPropertyPopulator {

    @Override
    public void populate(SolrIndexedPropertyModel source, IndexedProperty target) throws ConversionException {

        super.populate(source, target);

        //add this line
        target.setIsB2bUnit(source.getIsB2bUnit());

    }

}
```

Register the `propulator` into spring.

```xml
<!-- add this to your *-spring.xml -->

<alias name="myIndexedPropertyPopulator" alias="indexedPropertyPopulator" />

<bean id="myIndexedPropertyPopulator" class="com.foo.bar.MyIndexedPropertyPopulator" parent="defaultIndexedPropertyPopulator" />
```

4. The idea is to hook into this method `DefaultFieldNameTranslator.translateFromProperty(...)` and force it to add your specific `fieldQualifier` which is `b2bUnit.code` to the `fieldName` if the `isB2bUnit` of the `Indexedproperty` is `TRUE`.

The original `DefaultFieldNameTranslator.translateFromProperty(...)` is like this :

```java
protected String translateFromProperty(SearchQuery searchQuery, IndexedProperty indexedProperty, FieldType fieldType) {

    //...

    if(qualifierProvider != null && qualifierProvider.canApply(indexedProperty)) {

        Qualifier qualifier = qualifierProvider.getCurrentQualifier();
        fieldQualifier = qualifier != null?qualifier.toFieldQualifier():null;

    } else if(indexedProperty.isLocalized()) {

        fieldQualifier = searchQuery.getLanguage();

    } else if(indexedProperty.isCurrency()) {

        fieldQualifier = searchQuery.getCurrency();

    }

    //you have to add your else if here!!!

    return this.fieldNameProvider.getFieldName(indexedProperty, fieldQualifier, fieldType);

}
```

So create `MyFieldNameTranslator` that extends from `DefaultFieldNameTranslator` and override `translateFromProperty(...)`.

Note: `SomeB2bUnitService` this service is not real but it should be able to return the current b2bUnit.

```java
public class MyFieldNameTranslator extends DefaultFieldNameTranslator {

    //To be injected!!
    private SomeB2bUnitService someB2bUnitService;

    @Override
    protected String translateFromProperty(SearchQuery searchQuery, IndexedProperty indexedProperty, FieldType fieldType) {

        //...

        //...

        else if(indexedProperty.getIsB2bUnit()) {

            fieldQualifier = someB2bUnitService.getCurrentB2bUnit().getCode();

        }

        return this.fieldNameProvider.getFieldName(indexedProperty, fieldQualifier, fieldType);

    }

}
```

Register the `Translator` into `Spring` :

```xml
<!-- add this to your *-spring.xml -->

<alias name="myfieldNameTranslator" alias="fieldNameTranslator" />

<bean id="myfieldNameTranslator" class="com.foo.bar.MyFieldNameTranslator" parent="defaultfieldNameTranslator">

    <property name="someB2bUnitService" ref="someB2bUnitService" />

</bean>
```

5. Edit : now all what you have to do is to set `isB2bUnit` to `true` for `localStockForUnt`:

```xml
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true] ;name[unique=true] ;type(code) ;isB2bUnit
;$solrIndexedType ;localStockForUnt  ;boolean  ;true
```

Note : that some classes and beans may have been changed between Hybris versions but the concept will remains the same.